# Whenever I do git push to gitlab at 9pm, the push date that shows up on my gitlab repo will be the next days date. How do I fix this?

Tags: git, gitlab, push, git-push

Maybe somethings off with my timezone or something so I tried looking in my gitlab settings but no luck.

Comment: Gitlab does not (yet) support client timezones. It only supports server timezone. So if you are not in the same timezone as your gitlab server you're out of luck

Answer (score 1):

If it is a private GitLab instance, you can ask the admin [to change the timezone](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/workflow/timezone.html) at the server level.

But if it is about gitlab.com... [issue 37900](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ce/issues/37900) is about "Reflect my specified timezone throughout GitLab"
See also [issue 60000](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ce/issues/60000) "All times are displayed in EDT timezone" which will record evolution to GitLab for a better local timezone support.